# Thymeleaf Spring boot - input Localdate

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing a program in Spring boot and my database is postgre. i have a problem with thymeleaf. I try to input a localdate value but the value remain null. i dont have any problem with another values like String and int.

This is my Localdate value:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate einkaufsdatum;
```

and this is my thymeleafs code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addmaterial}" th:object="${material}" method="post">
    <p>Einkaufsdatum: <input type="date" th:value="*{einkaufsdatum}"  />
</form>
```

and this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="addmaterial", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSpeichern(@ModelAttribute Material material) {

//      System.out.println(material.getEinkaufsdatum()); for testing: print null value!
        materialRepository.save(material);
        return "materialverwaltung"; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem:
instead of:

```
<p>Einkaufsdatum: <input type="date" th:value="*{einkaufsdatum}"  />
```

i used this:

```
<p>Einkaufsdatum: <input type="date" th:field="*{einkaufsdatum}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate einkaufsdatum;
```

Try this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate einkaufsdatum = LocalDate.now();
```

Comment: What do you mean by current date ? Supposedly, when you initialize LocalDate.now(); it should save the current date? What date you are trying to save?